# Another mysql JOIN question

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have these tables:

```
classified:
classified_id (PK)
price
headline
cat_id // THIS IS ANYTHING FROM 1 TO 30 DEPENDING ON CATEGORY. IT IS SO THAT I CAN LINK WHICH CATEGORY TO USE IN THE CATEGORY TABLE BELOW
text
etc...

category:
cat_id (PK)
cat_name

category_options:
option_id (PK)
cat_id (FK) // FOREIGN KEY FROM CATEGORY TABLE...
option_name

option_values:
value_id (PK)
option_id (FK)
classified_id (FK)
value
```

How should I use join here, could anybody give me a quick example?

Here is an example of my setup:

```
      category
cat_id       cat_name
  1            cars

         category_options
option_id     cat_id    option_name 
   1             1         color
   2             1        gearbox

         option_values
 value_id       option_id       classified_id      value
    1              1                 22             red
    2              2                 22            manual

         classified
classified_id      price        headline         cat_id
    22              5000        'test'              1 //for cars
```

I want to be able to retrieve all options and their values from one category (in this ex cars) by only 'knowing' classified_id (which is 22 in this case).

Basically, I need help with the join statement...

and please don't use aliases in the code to simplify it for me :)

Thanks

Comment: Can there be multiple values per option? Do you want to select them based on `cat_id`, `classified_id` or both?

Comment: No, multiple options per category, but only one value per option name... I want to select them based on classified_id and cat_id, so let's say cat_id = 1 and classified_id = 22

Comment: Then there is imo no real reason to have a `value_id`, as both `option_id` and `classified_id` would make a primary key for the option values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't even need to explicitely specify the join here. It's just as simple that you want to get values from two tables (options and their values) where the option_ids are identical, and select only thos results where your cat & classified id matches.

```
SELECT cat_id, classified_id, option_id, option_name, value
  FROM option_values, category_options
 WHERE category_options.option_id = option_values.option_id
   AND classified_id = <?> AND cat_id = <?>
```

Comment: Hi... This works fine, thanks... But what If I would like to insert an ad. I know how to insert into the classifieds table, but I don't know how to insert the values of the option_values because there are more than one row that needs to be inserted.
The classifieds table is easy because it's just one row, but the option_values table has multiple rows per classified_id. Could you make a Insert statement for me as well? Thanks

Comment: For inserting, just execute the same insert statement multiple times (which changed values of course). Or you can use the syntax to add multiple values at once (`INSERT INTO tbl ( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES ( row1-1, row1-2, row1-3 ), ( row2-1, row2-2, row2-3), ...`) but most times that is not really the easiest way when working with dynamic content (it's easy to use that syntax when you know how many rows will be inserted, but for a dynamic number, just insert one row per statement).

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your main question, but I'd like to offer a suggestion that I believe will make your life easier...

1. Column names for PK columns -- just call all of them "`id`". Reduces the number of things you have to remember. Eliminates a major source of confusion and potential bugs.
2. Make table names consistent. I mean make them all the same form. You could make them all a singular noun or all a plural noun, but just make them all the same. Queries become easier to write and easier to understand.

   `classifieds`

   `categories`

   `category_options`

   `option_values`
3. Column names for FK cols -- like this: `parent_table_id`. For example: `classified.category_id`.
4. Eliminate any verbiage that doesn't contain new information. For example, `category.name` instead of `category.cat_name`.

Comment: re (1): I disagree. Especially when dealing with joins, it is a *lot* easier to have unique names for the *id* columns, so you can easily see which ids should be interpreted the same. I agree with (4), as those won't make an index, but for indexed columns, it is better to have unique names that spread over all tables where the same id is meant.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`SELECT category_option.option_name, option_values.value
FROM classified, category_option, option_values
WHERE classified.classified_id=?id AND classified.cat_id=category_options.cat_id AND option_values.option_id=category_options.option_id`

If you passed in 22 for the ?id parameter, you'd get 2 rows:

Color Red

Gearbox Manual